# WebStorm scss compiler error with transition/transform

Tags: css, sass

[image]

I am trying to make a web page, and I need to use some images with transform/transition. But the Scss compiler from WebStorm gives me that error.

What can I do ? See in the image above.

Comment: share your @mixin please.

Comment: There are no mixins.And the compiler still asks for it..

Comment: *"But the Scss compiler from WebStorm gives me that error."* 1) WebStorm has no "Scss compiler" -- the File Watcher just an interface that allows you to execute any external programs (scss compiler, which *you install yourself*) on file save. 2) If you look at the command that gets executed one more time (carefully this time), you will see what command gets executed .. and there is no WebStorm anywhere there. 3) Therefore this error comes from *scss compiler*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `@include` you need to `@mixin`.

**@MIXIN** example:

```
@mixin protoName($someValue) {
  -webkit-protoName: $someValue;
     -moz-protoName: $someValue;
      -ms-protoName: $someValue;
          protoName: $someValue;
}
```

**For yours code it can be something like this:**

```
@mixin transform($val) {
  -webkit-transform: $val;
     -moz-transform: $val;
      -ms-transform: $val;
          transform: $val;
}

main {
 .wrap {
    @include transform(rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0));
 }
}
```

**And your output look like this:**

```
main .wrap {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
       -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

You can read more about it [**Here**](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/)